# Bad: cors preflight error when I try fetching my RESTAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I request a POST method, im getting this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CrBB.png)

I need to register this data on my postgres data base (api) but when fetched I got error Preflight cors.
I try use mode: no-cors but unsuccesfull

Request Code:

```
async function PostOnDB(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;    
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Origin", 'http://localhost:5500')

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        date: form.date.value,
        local1: form.local1.value,
        local2: form.local2.value,
        tag: form.tag.value,
        equipament: form.equipament.value,
        description: form.description.value
    });

    var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',    
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: 'follow'
    };

    await fetch("https://maintenanceappbr.herokuapp.com/api/event", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
       
}
```

RestController code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class maintenanceEventResource {
@Autowired
    EventRepository eventRepository;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5500")
    @GetMapping("/events")
    public List<maintenanceEvent> listOfEvents(){
        return eventRepository.findAll();



@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5500")
    @PostMapping("/event")
    public maintenanceEvent RegisterEvent (@RequestBody maintenanceEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Event Registered");
        return eventRepository.save(event);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Added @CrossOrigin above @RestController

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")